# LEFT OUTER JOIN returning no results

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a query I prepared and have been working on. This query working in Psequel and PgAdmin, but will not work on my backend ( node js ) The library I am using with node js for the postgresql is node postgres 
 or 'pg'  https://node-postgres.com/  https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg  I find it very odd that it works fine with other applications but does not work intended in my backend. Please have a look at the information provided **below** High level what's going on here; I am checking to see if the users are friends or not by checking for a '1' value then returning true or false based on that ( open to suggestions ) after which I am proceeding to find the users workout routine by executing the second query ( not working ) What I expect is to get the rows I know is associated with my user like the other application(s) I have been using. The actual result to this query is ' [] '

```
getRoutine(username, user_id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
        client.connect()
            .then(() => console.log('connected'))
            .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
        const text = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT relationship_status FROM relationships FULL OUTER JOIN users ON users.user_id = relationships.user_one_id OR users.user_id = relationships.user_two_id WHERE users.username = $1 OR users.user_id = $2 AND relationships.relationship_status = 1)"
        const values = [username, user_id]
        const query = client.query(text, values)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.rows[0].exists === true) {
                    // find way to do this in single query
                    const text = "SELECT routine.workout, routine.personal_record, routine.workout_id, routine.upload_date FROM routine LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = routine.owner_id  WHERE users.username = $1"
                    const values = [username]
                    const query = client.query(text, values)
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data.fields)
                            resolve(data.rows)
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error)
                            reject();
                        })
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                reject();
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: looks like you don't have any record for this user inside `routine` table

Comment: It appears this way yes but I can assure you it exists in the table, as I mentioned it's only not working for the backend running this query on another app it will return exactly what I expect.

Comment: If there's records, your WHERE clause is filtering them out.  Remove parts of the WHERE clause until you get records, then you'll have discovered which filter is not working as you expected.  (AND and OR without brackets?!?!)

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the way this lib handles query args. I found out that my username being passed in so  Bob did not have any quotations wrapped around it hence causing it to return empty rows.. as it should be username = 'Bob'      Bob being $1 here.. that's what I have so far atleast it seems to do the trick hardcoding the name in for testing purposes.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but have you tried to replace ON users.user_id = routine.owner_id  WHERE users.username = $1 with ON users.user_id = routine.owner_id  AND users.username = $1 (note that I replaced WHERE with AND) ?

Comment: I have yes, running this now appears to have a similar effect as the above query upon first glance. Digging into this further i'm 80% certain when this query is executed it just looks like this users.username = Bob  which is illegal it needs to have single quotes; this explains no results. I guess a better question to ask at this point would be how to get around that with this library i'm using, Iv'e already tried .trim() and replace() in JS with no luck.

Comment: Your where condition on the outer table turns the outer join into an inner join. Move that condition to the JOIN condition.

Comment: thanks, do you mind showing me how to properly do this?

Comment: This also still does not explain why when I run this query using terminal or a sql client why I can get back exactly what I want but cannot get it back with the code in question I posted above; I find this really perplexing as you would think they would return the same results etc..